# SQL string comparison - why is this true?

Tags: sql, string, set

I'm trying to figure out why the following is false in SQL

```
'20001' >= '20000' AND '20001' < '2000:'
```

The character ':' has a higher value in the ASCII table than '1' so I expected the condition to be true, is that not how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the Collation: `Collations also determine the rules that sort and compare data`(from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16#Collation_Defn)) i.e. your database is sorting (choosing what is > or < ) based on your defined collation, rather than based on ASCII values)

Comment: I see, so whatever collation the database is using is currently indicating that : is of lesser value, interesting. Do you happen to know if there's documentation on what the character sets look like per collation?

Comment: Sorting rules are more complex than what it looks like.  e.g. for unicode, you can have a look at [UNICODE COLLATION ALGORITHM](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/), and an example of different results for one of the multiple considerations [here](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Variable_Weighting_Examples).  You can see some content of unicode collation [here](https://unicode.org/charts/collation/) - have a look at the "Help" link on the top left of that page to see some definitions to help understand the charts.